# Gmail Contextual Gadget - Custom extractor and precanned

Tags: gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am integrating AgileCRM with Google Apps & contextual gadget. I was able to crack the open-auth & gadget xml fairly quickly. However, I have issues with contextual gadget.

The requirement is simple - it needs to fetch sender's email address & name.

Next, if there are any email addresses in the body or subject, it needs to fetch that too.

I figured out that we cannot give multiple pre-canned extractors (the output was random in matching) and start writing a custom extractor. My extractor is fairly simple - it just gets from_name, from_personal and from_subject.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OpenCOBData id="Agile">
 <ExtractorSpec platform="gmail" language="en">
   <Response platform="gmail" format="cardgadget">
     <Output name="email_sender">{@__FROM_ADDRESS__}</Output>
     <Output name="email_name">{@__FROM_PERSONAL__}</Output>
     <Output name="email_subject">{@__SUBJECT__}</Output>
   </Response>
 </ExtractorSpec>
</OpenCOBData>
```

No issues with that. It works well too when used with the following extension.

```
<Extension id="FromEmailAddressExtractor" type="contextExtractor">
  <Name>Email ids in From</Name>
  <Url>623403448797:Agile</Url>
  <Triggers ref="AgileCRMGadget"/>
  <Scope ref="emailFrom"/>
   <Scope ref="emailName"/>
   <Scope ref="emailBody"/>
   <Scope ref="emailSubject"/>
   <Container name="mail"/>
</Extension>
```

So, I can get sender's name and email with no issues. However, the trouble occurs when I try to get the email addresses in subject or body now.

```
<Extension id="SubjectBodyEmailAddressExtractor" type="contextExtractor">
  <Name>Email ids in Subject or body</Name>
  <Url>google.com:EmailAddressExtractor</Url>
  <Param name="email" value=".*"/>
  <Triggers ref="AgileCRMGadget"/>
  <Scope ref="emailBody"/>
  <Scope ref="emailSubject"/>
  <Container name="mail"/>
</Extension>
```

When I add this, only this triggers the gadget and I miss out on the sender's email & name. It works individually as well but with both, only this triggers the gadget.

Is there a way I can make it work with both? IT seems to me that the first one to trigger will trigger the gadget.

Can I have a custom and precanned both in one with both the results? If yes, please let me know if I am going wrong somewhere.

Thanks.